# How do you use external Scala compiler with IDEA 12?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

How do you use external Scala compiler with IDEA ? I seem to have randomly appearing errors saying *"scala: Cannot connect to compile server at localhost/127.0.0.1:3200"*

Sometimes it works. Sometimes it doesn't. I can't find the pattern.

Here is what I have in the log

```
9:20:58 PM Auto make completed with errors
9:21:09 PM Using a new (SBT-based) Scala compiler.
           In case of any compilation problems you may enable the previous (internal) compiler by clearing:
           Project Settings / Compiler / Use external build
9:21:10 PM Scala compile server
           Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
           Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

9:21:12 PM Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 3 sec
```

I'm using

- IDEA 12.1 (129.161)
- Scala compiler 2.10.1
- Scala plugin 0.7.213
- JDK 1.7
- Windows 7

In Project Settings / Compiler / Use external build is checked.
In IDE Settings / Scala / Run compile server is checked.

Do I need to launch compiler server manually ? Anything else ?

UPD: Looks like bug to me. I posted JIRA ticket http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-5523

Comment: http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2012/12/28/a-new-way-to-compile/

Comment: @CrazyCoder it doesn't answer the question why compiler server is not launched though.

Comment: More details should be in [idea.log](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23352446). If you are on Mac, it may be environment issue, running IDEA like this may help: `open -a /Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ 12.app/`.

Comment: @CrazyCoder System reboot fixed it. It's absolutely not cool guys. I'll update this question and IDEA JIRA ticket when it happens again.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Well turned out it works only first debug session. All subsequent runs result in "Error: Could not find or load main class Test" error.

Comment: Report at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL with more details.

Comment: @CrazyCoder http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-5523

Answer (score 7):

You need to lower the heap size from 1024 to 512 or something. Then the compile server can be created and started. 
Tried with the InteliJ 13.0.2 (133.331) and Scala plugin 0.26.361

Comment: This worked for me, any idea why this makes a difference?

Comment: Not a slightest idea. I am a mainly C# guy, only occasionally do Java and Scala. This kind of heap size adjustment are never available for us low C# guy. :) Just kidding. I really don't know why.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Settings -> Compiler and uncheck "Use external build"

Comment: It works for me. Do you mind to provide any explanation on this tip?

Comment: Actually I found that out accidentally but it worked so I thought to share this.

Answer (score 1):

It normally works without having to change any settings. This sounds like either a port conflict, a result of a previous unclean shutdown, or insufficient heap size.

[image]

Try changing the compile server port by going to `Settings -> Scala (under IDE settings list, towards the bottom) -> TCP port`. Over there, you can also set a different max heap size.

The issue may be related to [this](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-5370) open ticket.

Comment: Nope, it didn't make any difference. In fact I don't see any processes that have set port open. Do you know who and when launches compile server ?

Comment: Since version 12, IntelliJ starts it. So right after you reboot and start IntelliJ, does it give you that exception?

Comment: @lexwriteshere Looks like it's IDEA bug. I added link to JIRA ticket. Thanks for your help, Alex !

Answer (score 1):

The bug I filed is marked as Fixed. JetBrains explanation is

*"Fixed" means that compilation now works by default, so the major problem (as the title states) is resolved.
However, an automatic initial compile server startup before auto-make is still cannot be easily implemented. That is why auto-make is still turned off by default for Scala projects. And, of course, we're going to support auto-make after all.*

Comment: Nope...Intellij 15 and i'm still getting it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with IntelliJ , if you open the event log (on the bottom right corner of IDE)you can see the error message that scala compiler is not configured with the jdk version and gives a link to set it up.

In `Settings > Languages and Frameworks > Scala Compile Server > JVM SDK` set the java you are using for the IDE as in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQ3u4.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this simple project I wrote, which uses the sbt-idea plugin. It should work out of the box with latest Intellij IDEA or Scala IDE (EClipse)

[skeleton](https://github.com/fractal/skeleton)

Answer (score 0):

Reducing Heap Size to 512 or 128 MB worked for me